# Translation for the word "variable"

Tags: translation

Is there any *real* translation for the word "variable" meaning the general concept of "a changing *something*" ?

Edit: Similar words are "parameters", "elements", "requirements".

*Example / Context*:

- "There are too many variables to find the perfect location for the movies": time, distance, habit, preference,...
- "What are you going to do today?", "The answer to this question has too many variables."
- (programming in general)

**Problem with "変数"** 
In general the word "variable" is translated as "変数". However, this is a wrong translation in many cases, as the Japanese literally means "variable number". This *might* make sense in calculus (*not math*), where this translation probably stems from, but it does not represent the actual meaning of *variable*.

Edit: **Background**
I use the word "variable" fairly often in English, so I need an understandable equivalent. "変数" works in Math and Advanced programming, but not in everyday parlance. Among other problems I encountered people wondering why I am suddenly talking about numbers.

Edit: **Towards the solution** (from the comments)

- パラメーター is difficult, as it's not Japanese
- 変動要因 seems a little difficult to understand, but
- 要因 sounds like a very good fit for everyday parlance.

Comment: The "variable" in your sentence seems to mean close to the word such as "parameters" "elements", "requirements", etc.　Does your 変数 is used to describe in a context fo computer programming?

Comment: I'm confused on 2 points:  (1) what do you mean by "calculus (*not math*)".  変数 is an excellent translation of *variable* in math where *variables* represent quantities that can change.  I agree with @kimiTanaka.  What you describe sounds like *parameter*.  (2) Are you expecting a one-to-one correspondence between words in one language (*variable* in English) and words in an unrelated language (Japanese).  I'm not sure how else to understand your words "*real* translation."  Why expect there to be a *constant* translation in all cases?  In short, clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I know, that was perhaps too many *puns*, but still I think they're applicable.

Comment: Did you actually check the definition of 変数 in Japanese? It need not be restricted to numbers.

Comment: @Leebo That's the *learned definition*, not the natural conclusion of the word components. If you encounter 変数 for the first time, you will read 変わる数（字）.

Comment: @A.Ellett `variable in math where variables represent quantities that can change`  I see people getting confused if they see differnt stuff in variables, like things, animals, habits. Although, part of this might stem from a lack of education. However, in the end the word still literally says 変 and 数.

Comment: @DarkTrick the use of 変数 for non-numeric variables is simply a convention that's used for the concept of a function in computer science as something that extends the original idea of mathematical functions (which only operate on numbers) to also operate on things that aren't numbers. In other words, if `x` is the 変数 in `f(x)`, in computer science you wouldn't restrict the possible values of `x` to just numbers.

Comment: @DarkTrick but we use words as their definitions have come to be, not strictly based on how they were originally formed...

Comment: The only "real" translation is that which people will understand. If you speak weird, a lot of people will unfortunately not understand you. To blame it on a "lack of education", is quite arrogant to say the least (you are the foreigner, not the native Japanese that don't understand you). Even your English examples, while understandable, are not really the natural way that normal people would phrase it. My suggestion would be to change how you speak when trying to use a language that is completely different from the one you're used to. That would be the most natural way.

Comment: @JansthcirlU while a few people argue that the term "function" only be used for maps where the codomain is a set of numbers, in general there is no such restrictions. Functions can be used for sets of non-numerical elements as well, in math.

Comment: @DarkTrick 変数 is the go-to translation for "variable", and 引数 is the go-to translation of "argument". Worrying about the kanji 数 seems to be an example of [etymological fallacy](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/logicalfallacies/Etymological-Fallacy) to me.

Answer (score 6):

IMO 変数 is not bad even in the context you provided. 変数 in math and programming contexts can safely hold non-numerical values such as strings, sets and functions. Still, if you do want to avoid 数, you can also use 変動要因 or パラメーター at least in that context.

**EDIT:** 不確定要素 is another common phrase that can be used in this context. [This entry](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=variable) has an example. (And I'd say it's very common despite its length; rest assured that any native Japanese adult understands this.)

Comment: I think you're onto something there naruto, I was thinking of other words that would fit the meaning of OP's context but *not* that of programming or math, and I think **factor** (要因) might be a good candidate. It clearly means either something that you need to take into account or a part of a multiplication (and there's no grey area like with variable or parameter).

Comment: I really like the idea of 要因. Maybe even 要素, close to the meaning of "parameter" (?) This goes a little away from the idea of *changing*, but might be better understandable than in everyday parlance.

Comment: @DarkTrick You're making sentences for educated adults, right? It's hard to imagine someone who doesn't understand 変動要因. If you like to use 要素, use 不確定要素 which is a fairly easy word despite its length.

Comment: @DarkTrick I've also run into situations where 変数 isn't understood like "variable" is in English outside of math contexts. Using 要因 instead worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

可変値 is another translation for “variable” that is used in technical fields and covers not only numbers but other types of values.

可変要素 may be used in non-technical contexts, though it still sounds somewhat technical.

Answer (score 0):

I feel, that both current answers ander their comments together are the best fit for an answer. As an effort to "accept both", I merged their content here and made the answer a **Community wiki**. Please feel free to edit and improve.

@naruto:

> IMO 変数 is not bad even in the context you provided. 変数 in math and programming contexts can safely hold non-numerical values such as strings, sets and functions. Still, if you do want to avoid 数, you can also use 変動要因 or パラメーター at least in that context.

> It's hard to imagine someone who doesn't understand 変動要因. If you like to use 要素, use 不確定要素 which is a fairly easy word despite its length.

@By137

> I've also run into situations where 変数 isn't understood like "variable" is in English outside of math contexts. Using 要因 instead worked for me.

@aguijonazo

> `可変値` is another translation for “variable” that is used in technical fields and covers not only numbers but other types of values.
>
> `可変要素` may be used in non-technical contexts, though it still sounds somewhat technical.

Comment: So wouldn't the answer to your question be *no, there's no single 'real' translation to fit all English meanings*?